# How to define the sort order of a dataframe?

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark-sql

I would like to sort a dataframe based on week number, and day of the week.

Week number variable is a double.

Day of the week is a text (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun).

Here is my dataframe:

```
week_number  |  day_of_week  |  job_count  | eff_rate
-----------------------------------------------------
1            | Fri           |  30         |  70
1            | Mon           |  50         |  80       
1            | Sat           |  340        |  20
1            | Sun           |  1          |  8
1            | Thu           |  3          |  40
1            | Tue           |  4          |  10
1            | Wed           |  50         |  70
2            | Fri           |  120        |  180
2            | Mon           |  12         |  80
2            | Sat           |  11         |  9
2            | Sun           |  80         |  11
2            | Tue           |  60         |  14
2            | Thu           |  4          |  23
2            | Wed           |  1          |  50
```

I think that I would need to define a function where I define how the sort should order the content of the variable.  Let's say the function is called manualsort.  What would manualsort() look like such that it can be used like this?

```
 df.sort(asc("week_number"), manualsort("day_of_week"))
```

The outcome would be something like this:

```
week_number  |  day_of_week  |  job_count  | eff_rate
-----------------------------------------------------
1            | Mon           |  50         |  80
1            | Tue           |  4          |  10       
1            | Wed           |  50         |  70
1            | Thu           |  3          |  40
1            | Fri           |  120        |  180
1            | Sat           |  340        |  20
1            | Sun           |  1          |  8
```

Comment: Before you get horribly downvoted, what have you tried so far? Can you show us the code that isn't working the way you want it to?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm new to Scala and not sure how to write a function

A Scala function follows the format you described; but sometimes an example is far more useful than a template

```
def addThem( a:Int, b:Int ) : Int = {
  var sum:Int = 0
  sum = a + b
  return sum
}
```

The key points:

- Items in the parenthesis of the function are variables passed to the
  function.
- The types those items must conform to are AFTER the
  variable name, with a colon `:` as a delimiter.
- The variables passed as parameters are separated by commas.
- If the function has a declared (instead of inferred) return type, it is the "type of the function signature" so it comes AFTER the function signature, using the same "colon constraining type" pattern (like `def getName() : String`)
- the equals sign afterwards assigns a code block to the function definition.  The code block must have a compatible exit type with the function signature (In this case, the code block must return something compatible with `Int`)
- Variable definitions within code blocks have the same `name:Type` format, but occasionally types are allowed to be inferred.

With these rules, I believe you will be able to start writing a few functions.  For Sorting, you effectively provide a Scala version of the Java `Comparator`, except that you have more ways to do it in Scala, as you don't need to wrap the function in Object-Oriented `Comparator` class clothing.